# Variable from block is put into a calculation but throws off wrong reading

Tags: java

I am having troubles with trying to retrieve a double variable that is already established outside the block and called inside but I want to return the value of the same variable so that I can apply it to a calculation.

the variable that I want returned is:

```
double quarter = 0;
```

but when I plug it into quarter in my first else/if statement, it plugs in `0` and not the value in my switch block. What can I do to retrieve the value?

```
        double quarter = 0;

        //Date entry will be calculated by how much KW user enters
        switch (input)
        {
            case "2/15/13":
                quarter = kwUsed * 0.10;
                break;
            case "4/15/13":
                quarter = kwUsed * 0.12;
                break;
            case "8/15/13":
                quarter = kwUsed * 0.15;
                break;
            case "11/15/13":
                quarter = kwUsed * 0.15;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid date");
        }


        //Declaring variables for calculations
        double base = 0;
        double over = 0;
        double excess = 0;

        double math1 = 0;
        double math2 = 0;


        //KW Calculations
        if (kwUsed <= 350)
        {
            base = quarter;

        }else if (kwUsed <= 500)
        {
            math1 = ((kwUsed - 350) * quarter);
            base = ((kwUsed * quarter) - math1);
            over = ((math1 * 0.1) + math1);

        }else if (kwUsed > 500)
        {
            math2 = ((kwUsed - 350) * 0.1);
            base = ((kwUsed * 0.1) - math2);
            math2 = ((kwUsed -350) - 50); 
            over = ((math2 * 0.1) + (15 * 0.1));
            double math3 =((kwUsed - 500) * 0.1);
            excess = ((math3 * 0.25) + math3);

        }
```

Edited to clarify question.

Comment: You've posted over 150 lines of code, with a very vague description. Please clarify your question, and edit the code to be as short as possible while demonstrating the problem. (I suspect you could probably manage with fewer than 50 lines pretty easily.)

Comment: If the input date is wrong then quarter will not be assigned to..

Comment: @JonSkeet I hope it is more easier to see now

Comment: @TonnyMadsen the date is already predetermined. That is not of concern. Whats giving me an issue is when i try to call back the quarter in my else/if statement, it does not send the data from my switch block. It would then calculate the else/if statement as the first declared value of "quarter" which is 0. I hope that make sense

Comment: Try print the value of quarter after the switch... Other than that I have no constructive ideas.

Comment: @TonnyMadsen I printed the quarter value and it came out the correct answer but my results are totally off. If I were to replace both "quarter" in my else/if statement with 0.12 the answer would read out: base:$42.00 over:$3.30 which is what I want but when quarter is left alone I get this reading: 

Baseline charge: $15,750.00
Over-baseline charge: $1,237.50
     Excess charge: $0.00
Total amount due: $16,987.50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be that `kwUsed = 0` in `switch` or date entered is wrong. `quarter` can't be zero if these values are correct.

```
double price = 0;
switch (input)
    {
        case "2/15/13":
            price = 0.10;
            break;
        case "4/15/13":
            price = 0.12;
            break;
        case "8/15/13":
            price = 0.15;
            break;
        case "11/15/13":
            price = 0.15;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid date");
    }


    //Declaring variables for calculations
    double base = 0;
    double over = 0;
    double excess = 0;

    double math1 = 0;
    double math2 = 0;


    //KW Calculations
    if (kwUsed <= 350)
    {
        base = kwUsed * price;

    }else if (kwUsed <= 500)
    {
        math1 = ((kwUsed - 350) * price);
        base = ((kwUsed * price) - math1);
        over = ((math1 * 0.1) + math1);

    }...
```

Comment: I replaced kwUsed = 0 in switch but I would get an error stating required int found double. Also date is entered exactly as what I have in quotes. I did a system print and the value came out to be what I wanted but when I placed the variable it would throw off the calculations.

Comment: Maybe I didn't write my answer clear enough. You shouldn't replace value of `kwUsed` to `0`. I assumed that it is `0` because You said that you get wrong values for `quarter`. Also why do you put your `quarter` to be `0.12` for testing values? Value of quarter is calculated based on value of `kwUsed` and I think that `kwUsed` is not `1` so `quarter` will probably be higher then `0.12`. Can You tell us what is the value of `kwUsed` when You get wrong results?

Comment: 0.12 is a rate during that month "4/15/13" that they charge to use per kw. The value of kw used is 375. The logic for the code is that they charge is base rate up to 350kw and charge an additional 0.1 for what is left over up to 500kw and above 500kw is an additional 0.25. If you replace "quarter" with 0.12 which the results should be base: 42.0 over: 3.3. When quarter in else/if state is left as is, the results is base:15,750 over: 1237.50 which does't make any sense.

Comment: Ok so math is correct. Maybe you have problem with business logic. For your input `input = 4/15/13;` and `kwUsed = 375`, `quarter` is equal `45`. Than You enter the first `else if(kwUsed <= 500){...}`. In there `math1 = ((375- 350) * 45); -> math1 = 1125`, 
          `base = ((375* 45) - 1125); -> base = 15750` and
           `over = ((1125* 0.1) + 1125); -> over = 1237.5`. These results based on your input are correct. As I said You maybe have problem with business logic part.

Comment: Maybe you don't even need quarter (as I understand). You can just set some `price` variable to correct value (0.10, 0.12, 0.15) based on your date input in `switch` statement and use that `price` to do calculations. In that case you should change the first `if(kwUsed<=350){ base = quarter; }` to something like this `if(kwUsed<=350) { base = kwUsed * price; }`.

Comment: I just realized what the issue was. Yes you are correct my business logic was incorrect. Where the quarter was, I needed a new variable that would only give out a reading of 0.1, 0.12, 0.15 and it had fixed my business logic.